# Reference the same variable multiple times without borrowing or cloning

Tags: rust, arduino, rust-no-std, rust-embedded

Currently, I am redefining the same variable (`dp`) multiple times to make the program work. However, this feels wrong, and I would think there would be a much better way to do this. For context, I am in a `no_std` environment, and compiling for avr-atmega328p (Arduino Uno), using the [avr-hal-template](https://github.com/Rahix/avr-hal-template).

```rs
#![no_std]
#![no_main]

use arduino_hal::hal::wdt;
use motor_shield::{dc::DcMotor, init_pwm, Motor};
use panic_halt as _;

#[arduino_hal::entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let dp = arduino_hal::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let pins = arduino_hal::pins!(dp);

    let dp = arduino_hal::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let mut pwm = init_pwm(None, dp, pins).unwrap();
    let mut dc_motor = DcMotor::try_new(&mut pwm, Motor::Motor1).unwrap();

    let dp = arduino_hal::Peripherals::take().unwrap();
    let mut watchdog = wdt::Wdt::new(dp.WDT, &dp.CPU.mcusr);
    watchdog.start(wdt::Timeout::Ms4000).unwrap();

    loop {
        let _ = dc_motor.set_throttle(&mut pwm, 0.5);
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(1000);
        let _ = dc_motor.set_throttle(&mut pwm, 0.0);
        arduino_hal::delay_ms(1000);
        watchdog.feed();
    }
}
```

For context, here is the `init_pwm` function:

```rs
pub fn init_pwm(i2c: Option<I2c>, dp: Peripherals, pins: Pins) -> Result<Pca9685<I2c>, MotorError> {
    let i2c = if let Some(i2c) = i2c {
        i2c
    } else {
        I2c::new(
            dp.TWI,
            pins.a4.into_pull_up_input(),
            pins.a5.into_pull_up_input(),
            50000,
        )
    };

    let address = Address::from(60);

    let mut pwm = Pca9685::new(i2c, address).map_err(|_| MotorError::PwmError)?;
    pwm.enable().map_err(|_| MotorError::PwmError)?;
    pwm.set_prescale(4).map_err(|_| MotorError::PwmError)?;
    Ok(pwm)
}
```

The one thing I could think to do was borrow dp, but that wouldn't work because the functions don't accept references. I also cannot clone dp because it does not implement the Clone trait.

Comment: Side note, this doesn't just look bad -- it won't work. `arduino_hal::Peripherals::take()` is going to return `None` on all but the first invocation, so the rest of them will panic due to the `.unwrap()`.

Comment: What's `motor_shield`? I can't find it on crates.io.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman It's a library based off of [adafruit_motorkit](https://crates.io/crates/adafruit_motorkit) I made to control an Adafruit motor shield.

Comment: If you made it, can't you make it so it doesn't consume the peripherals, only borrow them? It will be trivial then.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I change peripherals to be borrowed, I then get the error:
`Cannot move 
cannot move out of dp.TWI which is behind a shared reference [E0507] move occurs because dp.TWI has type arduino_hal::pac::TWI, which does not implement the Copy trait`. 

Since the issue might have to partially do with the `init_pwm` function, I have edited the post to include it for clarification.

Comment: Assuming the functions you use don't require access to the same parts of the peripherals, the best way forward will be to destructure the `Peripherals` and only give each function access to the part(s) it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by Chayim Friedman, I finally figured out a solution. I changed the `init_pwm` function to require `WDT` instead of the full Peripherals, as that was all it needed. I was then able to call the function with just `dp.TWI` instead of `dp`.

```rs
pub fn init_pwm(i2c: Option<I2c>, twi: TWI, pins: Pins) -> Result<Pca9685<I2c>, MotorError> {
  // ...
  else {
    I2c::new(
      twi,
      pins.a4.into_pull_up_input(),
      pins.a5.into_pull_up_input(),
      50000,
    )
  }
```

```rs
// in main.rs
fn main() -> ! {
  let dp = Peripherals::take().unwrap();
  let pins = arduino_hal::pins!(dp);
    
  let mut pwm = init_pwm(None, dp.TWI, pins).unwrap();
  let mut dc_motor = DcMotor::try_new(&mut pwm, Motor::Motor1).unwrap();
    
  let mut watchdog = wdt::Wdt::new(dp.WDT, &dp.CPU.mcusr);
  watchdog.start(wdt::Timeout::Ms4000).unwrap();
  // ...
}
```